# How to make freebsd's terminal prompt show current directory

Tags: freebsd

My freebsd terminal always only show "#"
I want it show current directory.
How can I manage that?
Thank you indeed!

Comment: That's because you're logged in as root.

Comment: Check here for all the shell customization information you can stand: http://www.geekvenue.net/chucktips/jason/chuck/1039988302/index_html

Comment: type pwd (print working directory) for quick look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if using bash shell - in .bash_profile add:

```
PS1="[\u@\h:\w] " 
case `id -u` in
      0) PS1="${PS1}# ";;
      *) PS1="${PS1}$ ";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

In FreeBSD 10.2, `\u` does not appear to work.

I replaced it with `´whoami´` as in the original prompt.
Now it works fine.

```
PS1="´whoami´@\h:\w" 
case `id -u` in
    0) PS1="${PS1}# ";;
    *) PS1="${PS1}$ ";;
esac
```